# How to call a jQuery method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say for example, using javascript i would normally call a method like this

```
<a href ="" onclick="javascriptMethod()">Link</a>
```

and implement the method like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function javascriptMethod(){
 //codes
}
</script>
```

For some reaon on most jQuery documents all I can find is

```
$("").click(function(){
  //codes
});
```

Can we not make onclick call on jQuery?

CLEARIFICATION: Instead of `$().click` I need to call the method for the  itself due to existing div array which I cannot change. I know how to do it on JavaScript and is quite easy. The question is, can I not call jQuery method for the an element like `<img onclick="jQueryMethod" />` ?

I need to pass a value to the method, thats the most important bit. Since the elements are in an array, i cannot figure out which element[x].

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? What you are asking doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What is it you don't understand from the examples? http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: onclick and all the other inline events are an old, disgusting, intrusive way to register events. That's why people don't use them anymore when writing modern HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: What is exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Basicly the answer to your last question is no. It is like  @ThiefMaster said.

Comment: Still need more clarification. Since you know how to do what you want in "javascript but not jQuery", then please include the code that would do it in javascript.

Comment: @tHIEFMASTER, thats the answer i was looking for. But yours is a comment, how to mark as an answer.

Comment: `$('img').click(function(){ ..codes... });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick` and all the other inline events are an old and intrusive way to register events. That's why people don't use them anymore when writing modern HTML/JavaScript.

Some advantages of registering them via JavaScript instead of using inline events is that you can call functions that are not in the global scope and use closures to have non-global variables available which were defined outside the event function. It also causes a cleaner structure since you don't mix JavaScript with HTML.

You also have the advantage that you can easily bind a function to lots of elements via e.g. a class selector: `$('.someclass').click(someFunction);`

Comment: I thought you approved a more complete answer.

Comment: @Florent: That's what happens with unclear questions like this one. Actually I didn't even think that what I initially posted as a comment would be what the OP's looking for.

Comment: SO can piss you off sometimes, even more when someone has put as much effort in the answer as Florent. But that's just the way the world goes round, and hence I don't answer this kind of "question".

Answer (score 3):

This is how we make click call.

Accessing control by its id and calling click.

```
$("#IdOfClickableControl").click();
```

We can also do it by trigger

```
$("#IdOfClickableControl").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Like this?: 
<a href="" $("").click()></a>.

Comment: @MrGhimire 1. your quotation is broken. 2. JS inside `href` attributes require the `javascript:` prefix.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following HTML:

```
<a id="mylink" href="#">Link</a>
```

You could add a listener like this:

```
$("#mylink").click(function() {
    // Call the method you want
    javascriptMethod();

    // Prevent the default behaviour
    return false;
});
```

If you don't use a link but a `span` or a `button` (no default behaviour):

```
<span id="myelement">Click here</span>
```

You could simply write:

```
$("#myelement").click(javascriptMethod);
```

If you have multiple links, you could add a class to each links (i.e.: `callback`) and then do:

```
$("a.callback").click(function() {
    javascriptMethod();
    return false;
});
```

**Edit 1:** Added the method call as the OP requested.

**Edit 2:** Handle multiple links

Comment: +1, best answer so far. I'd use `href="javascript:void(0);"` which is longer but doesn't rely on anchor hacks. But that is just me. Just to add, using `href="javascript:void(0);"` you wouldn't have to `return false` in the end of your function to prevent the browser from scrolling to top, but that's just it.

Comment: @florent, There are a bumebr of myLinks like, #myLink1, #myLink2 etc. and writing methods for each is not the right way to go. Is there any way you could suggest me.

Comment: You could add a class to each links (i.e.: `callback`) and then do `$("a.callback").click(function() { javascriptMethod(); return false; });`

Comment: @MrGhimire Give them a common class then `$('.myLinks').click(function(){//etc`, or wrap your desired links inside an element: `$('#myDivLinks a')` to select all links inside of it, or ultimately concatenate all of them `$('#myLink1, #myLink2')`. There are many ways to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn’t define the `onclick` function directly in the `HTML` source, it’s much cleaner to use an identifier and then attach the handler using jQuery, such as `id`:

```
<a href="" id="mylink">Link</a>
```

Then select it using a jQuery selector and add the click handler like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        // do stuff
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<a href="" id="thingy">Link</a>
```

js

```
$("#thingy").click(function(){
  // the content of your method here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("").click(function(){
//codes
});
```

This method is event handler. When end user click on your anchor tag thiw will get called so you don't have to call any method as such. 
For more on event handling in jQuery [refer](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)